# Spring MVC validation: minimum one field required. At least one field required

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, validation

I do a search by criteria with an DTO entity for **filter** in the front-end of my application:

```
public class MyFilter implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AccessType accessType;
    private List<MyType> userType;
    private List<OfficeLocation> officeLocation;
    private List<Language> languages;
    private String country;

}
```

and getters and setters.

In my **controller**:

```
@RequestMapping
public ModelAndView list(@ModelAttribute("filter") MyFilter myFilter, BindingResult result) {        
    final ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("list");
    // validate
    MyFilterValidator.validate(myFilter, result);
    mav.addObject("filter", myFilter);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return mav;
    }
    // ...
    return mav;
}
```

I want to validate the search form filter by a **validator class**:

public class MyFilterValidator implements org.springframework.validation.Validator {

```
@Override
public void validate(Object object, Errors errors) {
    final MyFilter myFilter = (MyFilter) object;

    if (myFilter == null) {
        errors.reject("error.one.field.required");
    } else {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(myFilter.getName()) && myFilter.getAccessType() == null
                && myFilter.getUserType() == null && myFilter.getLanguages() == null
                && StringUtils.isEmpty(myFilter.getCountry())
                && myFilter.getOfficeLocation() == null) {
            errors.reject("error.one.field.required");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class inClass) {
    return MyFilter.class.equals(inClass);
}
```

}

I need to validate if one field is filled, minimum one field of my Filter class is filled. How can I do that in a simple way?
I need to check each attribute : StringUtils.isEmpty or .size()<=0, ... ?
Is it possible to iterate over each property and check if one of them is not null?
To know if one field is fill?

Answer (score 1):

If you need this test very often, then it would be worth to implement a small function that inspect some annotated fields of the DAO by reflection.

```
public DAO {
   public String nevermind;

   @AtLeastOneOfThem
   public String a; 

   @AtLeastOneOfThem
   public String b; 
}

/**
  * Return True if at least on of the fields annotated by @AtLeastOneOfThem
  * is not Empty. 
  * THIS IS PSEUDO CODE!
  */
public static boolean atLeastOneOfThemIsNotEmpty(Object o) {
   for(Field field : getFieldsAnnotatedWith(AtLeastOneOfThem.class, o) {
      if (field.get() != null && !field.get().empty()) {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

If this is too much work, then it would be the fastet way to implment the check in the tradtional handwritten way.